# Как присвоить ip адрес конкретному сетевому адаптеру в Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, unix

Как присвоить ip адрес конкретному сетевому адаптеру в Linux/Unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для это необходимо открыть терминал, и выполнить следующею команду (предполагается, что надо настроить адаптер eth1 на ip адрес 192.168.11.130)

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.11.130
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ip addr add dev eth1 192.168.11.130
```

Answer (score 2):

Для настройки сетевых интерфейсов, используйте утилиты `ip` или  `ifconfig`. Ниже информация касаемо утилиты `ifconfig`.

Вывести информацию по всем интерфейсам:

> sudo ifconfig -a

```
Интерфейсы начинающиеся на eth* - проводные.
Интерфейсы начинающиеся на wlan* - беспроводные.
```

Вывести информацию по указанному интерфейсу wlan0:

> sudo ifconfig wlan0

Включить сетевой интерфейс wlan0

> sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

Выключить сетевой интерфейс wlan0

> sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

Установка IP адреса интерфейсу wlan0

> sudo ifconfig wlan0 10.0.5.2

Установка маски подсети для интерфейса wlan0

> sudo ifconfig wlan0 netmask 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 1):

Или **sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces**

И там:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.22.7.4 #IP-Адресс
netmask 255.255.0.0 #Маска подсети
network 172.22.0.0 #Сеть (начало диапазона сети)
broadcast 172.22.255.255 #Сеть (коне диапазона сети)
gateway 172.22.0.1 #Шлюз
dns-nameservers 172.22.0.1 #Днс сервер
dns-search stavr.net.ua #Сетевой домен если есть
```

Последние два пункта не обезательно писать.

А если нужен алиас то:

```
iface eth0:1 inet static
```

И тут дальше идет описание как и в обычном интерфейсе.